# AWS EC2 or ELB issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am running my web app (developed in python & flask) on AWS ELB with 10 EC2 instances. I am getting throughput 600 requests/sec.
But, before one month with same configuration I was getting throughput 7000 requests/sec.
I have checked all configuration in my web server(Nginx) to increase though put . All is good.

Does anybody has idea why I am facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem in AWS, or a problem in your application.

Start debugging by reading CloudWatch ELB statistics (specially Latency) and then the logs for your application. There must be a bottleneck somewhere.